# Trouble with CurlException in GAE - "Couldn't resolve host"

Tags: php, api, google-app-engine, curl

I am having trouble in Google App Engine using Guzzle PHP calling to https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLM/categories/all

exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 6: Couldn't resolve host 'api.mercadolibre.com' [url] https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLM/categories/all' in /base/data/home/apps/s~starry-journal-99514/1.385597037367626041/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php:359

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your app billing enabled? Curl uses sockets, which only works for paid apps: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_cURL_support

Comment: @Mars Thats the correct fix.